# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "today" at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1550)

Tags: java, android, parcelable, aidl, android-binder

when i use AIDL,it occured。
this is the exception：

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid int: "明天天气怎么样"
                               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1550)
                                                                      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
                                                                      at com.uurobot.voicesrc.remote.IMsgCallBack$Stub$Proxy.interceptRobotAction(IMsgCallBack.java:82)
```

this is the aidl

```
@Override 
public boolean interceptRobotAction(java.lang.String result) throws android.os.RemoteException {
    android.os.Parcel _data = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
    android.os.Parcel _reply = android.os.Parcel.obtain();
    boolean _result;
    try {
        _data.writeInterfaceToken(DESCRIPTOR);
        _data.writeString(result);
        mRemote.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_interceptRobotAction, _data, _reply, 
        0);
        _reply.readException();**//82 exception happen at this line**
        _result = (0!=_reply.readInt());
    }
    finally {
        _reply.recycle();
        _data.recycle();
    }
    return _result;
}
```

**_reply.readException();//82 exception happen at this line**

Comment: thanks for format my code!@vins

Comment: i have solve my problem-----when exception happend in the method aidl defined, it will display this. so when happen this ,you need check your code first.